# Object with dynamic keys not able to generate Parse JSON schema in power automate

Tags: json, jsonschema, power-automate

I am making one API call in Power Automate and the response I am receiving the below JSON

```
{
"paging": {
    "start": 0,
    "count": 10,
    "links": [],
    "total": 3
},
"elements": [
    {
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
        "createdAt": 1704446818959,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "lastModifiedAt": 1704446818959,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "publishedAt": 1704446818959,
        "author": "urn:li:organization:101414444",
        "id": "urn:li:share:7148968102884841984",
        "distribution": {
            "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
            "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },
        "content": {
            "media": {
                "altText": "",
                "id": "urn:li:image:D4D22AQHbdiWdPzeHtg"
            }
        },
        "commentary": "Hi Test",
        "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "isEditedByAuthor": false
        }
    },
    {
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
        "createdAt": 1704285674051,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "lastModifiedAt": 1704285674096,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "publishedAt": 1704285674051,
        "author": "urn:li:organization:101414444",
        "id": "urn:li:ugcPost:7148292213186180096",
        "distribution": {
            "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
            "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },
        "content": {
            "multiImage": {
                "images": [
                    {
                        "altText": "",
                        "id": "urn:li:image:D4D22AQFnjGKot4DBIg"
                    },
                    {
                        "altText": "",
                        "id": "urn:li:image:D4D22AQEzSmXKu93lmw"
                    },
                    {
                        "altText": "",
                        "id": "urn:li:image:D4D22AQGMb7DQf3s7zA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "commentary": "Hi There",
        "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "isEditedByAuthor": false
        }
    },
    {
        "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false,
        "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
        "createdAt": 1703744862033,
        "lastModifiedAt": 1703744862095,
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "publishedAt": 1703744862033,
        "author": "urn:li:organization:101414444",
        "id": "urn:li:share:7146023559452666882",
        "distribution": {
            "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
            "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
        },
        "commentary": "Hi Community!",
        "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "isEditedByAuthor": false
        }
    }
]
}
```

In my next step, I am using Parse JSON to read the above JSON like
[image]

In the Schema input of the above image, I tried to generate from the sample and it asked sample payload, where I put the above JSON and it generated the below Schema.

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "paging": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "start": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "count": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "links": {
                "type": "array"
            },
            "total": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    },
    "elements": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "createdAt": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "lifecycleState": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lastModifiedAt": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "visibility": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "publishedAt": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "author": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "distribution": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "feedDistribution": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": {
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "media": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "altText": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "id": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "commentary": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lifecycleStateInfo": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "isEditedByAuthor": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "isReshareDisabledByAuthor",
                "createdAt",
                "lifecycleState",
                "lastModifiedAt",
                "visibility",
                "publishedAt",
                "author",
                "id",
                "distribution",
                "commentary",
                "lifecycleStateInfo"
            ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is successfully running when **content** object has **media** value like

[image]

but it is failing when **content** object has **multiImage** value like

[image]

so, I am not sure if we can generate a Schema for the above JSON or not? or any other way to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work...

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "paging": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "start": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "count": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "links": {
          "type": "array"
        },
        "total": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "elements": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "createdAt": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "lifecycleState": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lastModifiedAt": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "visibility": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "publishedAt": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "author": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "distribution": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "feedDistribution": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": {
                "type": "array"
              }
            }
          },
          "content": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "media": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "altText": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "multiImage": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "images": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": [
                      {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                          "altText": {
                            "type": "string"
                          },
                          "id": {
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "commentary": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lifecycleStateInfo": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "isEditedByAuthor": {
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "isReshareDisabledByAuthor",
          "createdAt",
          "lifecycleState",
          "lastModifiedAt",
          "visibility",
          "publishedAt",
          "author",
          "id",
          "distribution",
          "commentary",
          "lifecycleStateInfo"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the last array element "content" is blank. How can I check if "content" is set/or blank in the "Apply to each" loop?

Comment: In the last element it isn't blank but non-existent. You use can use `equals(items('Apply to each')?['content'], null)`. Did the schema in the answer work for your scenario?

Comment: In Apply to ecah of 'elements'->then If condition. How can I check if 'content' has 'media' or 'multiImage'?

Comment: Same way: `items('Apply to each')?['content/media']` `is equal to` `null` Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78fPF.png